# split ressources between users - Spark cluster

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, cluster-computing

I'm administrating a spark cluster, and I have a question.
    In my cluster, I have 3 users (userA,userB,userC), and 80 cores, 100G RAM ... 
    I would like to split those ressources between users, in way that :

```
userA : can use 60% of ressources 
userB : can use 30% of ressources
userC : can use 10% of ressources
```

do you have any ideas how to do it ? 
best regards !

Comment: Standalone, Mesos or YARN?

Comment: But, with standalone I can't say that a userA can use up to 60% of ressources !